# R auto.arima why number of residual values is equal to number of observations

Tags: r, arima, residuals

Here is my auto.arima example:

```
library(forecast)
vec <- ts(sin(1:15))
arima_fit <- auto.arima(vec)
```

All of the following values are the same

```
NROW(arima_fit$residuals)
NROW(arima_fit$fitted)
NROW(arima_fit$x)
```

I am curious why? Since this is autoregressive model I would expect number of fitted/residual values to be strictly less than number of observations, at least by p (number fo lags) parameter of ARIMA.

Comment: This would be true if the model were estimated by conditional least squares, but here it is likely estimated by maximum likelihood.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thank you! Let us take very simple case `x_n = a_0+a_1*x_(n-1)+a_2*x_(n-2)`, this is simple autoregressive case. In order to obtain `x_0` the first value, we need to have the initial 2 values.  Where are these two values are coming from? I am not sure I understand why it matters how coefficients of the model are estimated.

Comment: When using maximum likelihood, the initial values are estimated together with the model coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be true if the model were estimated by conditional least squares, but here it is likely estimated by maximum likelihood. The initial values are estimated together with the model coefficients.

For immediate details of the R implementation of ARIMA, see the [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.1.1/topics/arima) for the R function `arima` from the `stats` package (scroll down to the section Fitting Methods). For more general information on fitting ARIMA models, consult a time series textbook such as Hamilton ["Time Series Analysis"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691042893/time-series-analysis) (1994). Some Cross Validated threads may be helpful, too; I would start by combing through the results of [this query](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bestimation%5D+%5Barima%5D+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Thank you! Could you share any references, so that I can look at computations?

Comment: @user1700890, I have updated my answer to address your question.